# What is half-vector of light in glsl?

Tags: math, opengl, glsl

*I'm playing with per pixel lighting shaders and i don't know one thing:* What is half vector of light source ?

```
vec3 halfVector = normalize(gl_LightSource[1].halfVector.xyz);
```

I would like i you can explain it in math rows, i understand math better than words :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this post](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=360365):

> A "halfway vector" (if you mean that by "half vector") is the unit vector at the half angle between two other vectors. Normally the halfway vector [...] is computed between the vector to the viewer v and the light source l:

```
h := ( v + l ) / || v + l ||
```

The half vector therefore is the unit [angle bisector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Angle_bisector) of view- and light vector.

**Edit:** For a complete explanation of the lighting model including the half vector, just see the [Blinn-Phong wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model)

Comment: is this really correct? if v is {0,5} and l is {2,0} then the angle between h and v is ~21 degrees and the angle between h and l is ~69 degrees. assuming that (v+l) is {2,5} and ||v+l|| is Sqrt[29]

Comment: I think v and l are assumed normalized here.

Answer (score 4):

The the answer by Dario is correct, but since the question was for GLSL, here is the appropriate code:

```
vec3 hf = normalize(v + l);
```

Generally the "THE" half vector is the vector between the light and the view vector. It is generally used as input to the specular bit of the Blinn-Phong equations.

Answer (score 0):

this was my solution:

```
vec3 halfVector = normalize(lightDirection + viewDirection);
```

EDIT: it is not 100% correct but working when you want to do it more simple.